# Jquery commands not performed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Have a nice time .  I downloaded the latest compressed version of jquery from lesson https://jquery.com/download/ (Download the compressed, production jQuery 3.6.0)

Then in the html document I called as follows:

```
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title> Title </title>
    <script src = "js / jquery-3.6.0.min.js"> </script>
</head>
```

Then in body I wrote jquery commands like this:

```
<script> 
    $ ('# ulmenu li').hover (function () {
       $ ('> div', this) .fadein ();
      }, function () {
       $ ('> div', this) .fadeout (  );
      }) 
</script>
```

But the commands are not correct at all and the phpstorm software has a problem.  Disadvantages also include $ .hover.  fadein.  is fadeoute ... please tell me where the problem is.  Thankful

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish and what happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

First I would say, check if the jquery is injected in your page.

Just see your devtools and check any errors in network tabs. I also see some typos in your code. Not sure if they got in  while pasting the code, but remove the spaces like here `js / jquery-3.6.0.min.js` and also in `<script>`.